# Каждую секунду выводится список файлов ajax-ом. Как подвязать ondblclick-событие, если постоянно происходит обновление?

Tags: ajax, события, setinterval

Нужно постоянно отслеживать, какие файлы лежат в папке, поэтому каждую секунду этот список выводится в `div.list` ajax-ом. Мне нужно при `ondblclick` на `ul > li` хотя бы в консоль вывести название файла (`li.innerHTML`). Как правильно сделать ведь обновление `div.list` происходит каждую секунду?

```
const list = document.querySelector('.list');

function show_files(){  
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'handler-list.php');
    xhr.send();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState != 4){
            return; 
        }
        if(xhr.status == 200){
             list.innerHTML = xhr.response;
        }
        else{
            txt_out.value = 'Не удалось связаться с сервером!';
        }
    }
}

function start(){
    id = setInterval('show_files()', 1000);
}

document.querySelector('body > .list').onload = start();
```

Comment: Так обновляйте список `div.list` только тогда когда у вас добавился новый файл в директории. Если список ответа не отличается от списка в диве то не обновляете ничего и тогда можно нажать на название файла.

Comment: @Dmitriy Kondratiuk, а как сравнить xhr.response и div.list (хотя точнее .list.childNodes)?